# Converting a decimal integer to a sexagesimal number

Tags: c, datetime, time, arduino

i am looking for simple c code that convert decimal to  sexagesimal .Here what i am trying to do.

```
t1=13:05
t2=5:30 
t1 minute=13*60+05=785
t2 in minute=5*60+30=330
t1-t2=455minute
time diff=455/60=7 hour 58 minute ("this wrong consideration since value in decimal");
but expected is 7 hour 35 minute
```

Comment: Is there any program availble which convert UTC to local time.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking how to convert a number from the decimal base to another base, i.e. 60, if I understand you correctly. I think that a general algorithm will help you get the general idea behind your question, try this http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html

Thumbs up for tinkering with the sexagesimal system, it has great "mathematical beauty" and I haven't seen no one in ages doing something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use *integer* division to get the number of whole hours, then modulo to get the number or minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do integer division of `455/60` and expect to get hours and minutes directly. It will be in hours and fraction.

Instead you can:

```
diff_in_hours = (t1 - t2) / 60;
diff_in_mins = (t1 - t2) % 60;
printf("difference in time is %d : %d", diff_in_hours, diff_in_mins);
```